# Sort an array of objects after $q.all resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-promise

Coding an app with AngularJs. I want to retrieve a list of all groups a user has joined.

I wrote the following:

```
controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $q, $localStorage, AuthService, DatabaseService, GroupService) {
  console.log("*** DashCtrl ***");
  var user = AuthService.currentUser;
  $scope.user = user;
  var uid = $scope.user.auth.uid;

  $scope.joinedGroups = [];

  var tmpGroups = [];
  var addGroupDetailsPromises = [];

  GroupService.getUserJoinedGroupsArray($scope.user.auth.uid)
  .then(function(groups) {
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
      var tmpGroup = {};
      tmpGroup.id = groups[i];
      addGroupDetailsPromises.push(addGroupDetails(tmpGroup));
      tmpGroups.push(tmpGroup);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error retrieving groups: ', error);
  });

  // Once all details have been added to groups, sort groups
  $q.all(addGroupDetailsPromises).then(function() {
    console.log(tmpGroups.length);
    tmpGroups.sort(function(a, b) {
      console.log('a: ', a.details.timestamp);
      console.log('b: ', b.details.timestamp);
      return a.details.timestamp - b.details.timestamp;
    });

    console.log(tmpGroups);
    $scope.joinedGroups = tmpGroups;
  }).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });

  function addGroupDetails(tmpGroup) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      GroupService.getGroupDetailsObj(tmpGroup.id).then(function(details) {
        tmpGroup.details = details;
        tmpGroup.display = {};
        var eventDate = new Date(details.timestamp);
        var today = new Date();

        if (eventDate >= today) {
          tmpGroup.display.day = eventDate.getDate();
          tmpGroup.display.month = monthNames[eventDate.getMonth()].substr(0, 3);
          tmpGroup.display.time = eventDate.getHours() + ":" + eventDate.getMinutes();

        }

        resolve();
      });
    });

    return promise;
  };

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

})
```

My array of groups (tmpGroups) never gets sorted. The length of the array equals 0 based on what outputs my console.log(tmpGroups.length)... I guess that is the reason why it never gets sorted.

But I don't understand that results because my array is supposed to be filled with all the information as I used $q.all that waits for all promises to be resolved.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because GroupService.getUserJoinedGroupsArray is async call. You have to wait until it finished then push the list to tmpGroups and then execute the promise. Try put promise inside then

```
GroupService.getUserJoinedGroupsArray($scope.user.auth.uid)
  .then(function(groups) {
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
      var tmpGroup = {};
      tmpGroup.id = groups[i];
      addGroupDetailsPromises.push(addGroupDetails(tmpGroup));
      tmpGroups.push(tmpGroup);
    }

    // Once all details have been added to groups, sort groups
    $q.all(addGroupDetailsPromises).then(function() {
       console.log(tmpGroups.length);
       tmpGroups.sort(function(a, b) {
         console.log('a: ', a.details.timestamp);
         console.log('b: ', b.details.timestamp);
         return a.details.timestamp - b.details.timestamp;
    });

      console.log(tmpGroups);
     $scope.joinedGroups = tmpGroups;
    }).catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
    })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error retrieving groups: ', error);
  });
```

Comment: Hey guys, I am having a similar issue....looks almost the same, an async issue but can't figure out where my sort needs to go to presort my results before being returned to the controller.  Could you take a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494215/sorting-q-all-responses-not-working