# Sorting $q.all() responses not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-promise

My $q.all() is working fine.  The below code is in my primary service and when done everything is returned to the controller correctly.  However I am trying to pre-sort the final array returned to the controller its not working.  The sort function itself works - its the identical function in my controller that I use to manually sort the results on my template page.  Its just the initial results don't come back sorted.

I know its an async issue, but can't figure out where the sort needs to go before the results are returned.

```
// SERVICE
var groups = [] ; 
$q.all([promise1(),promise2(),promise3(),promise4(),promise5(),promise6()]).then(function(response){  
    var z=0 ;
    for (var y=0;y<response.length;y++) {  
          // process each promise as a complete 
          //     value: [0][{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6}],
          //            [1]:[{a:7,b:8,c:9},{a:10,b:11,c:12}]
       for (var x=0;x<response[y].length;x++) {  
          // process the components of each promise 
          // value [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6}]
          response[y][x].ID = z++ ;  // reassign primary 'list' ID
          groups.push(response[y][x]) ;  // push preformatted component
                                         // to 'groups' to be passed
                                         // back to controller
       }
    }
    var sortType = getDB("sortOption") ;
    sortGroups(sortType) ;  // global 'groups' is already 
                            //   in 'sortGroups()'
});

return {
  all: function() {
    return [groups,sortType] ;
  }

// CONTROLLER
$scope.groups = ServiceGroups.all() ;
```

In the controller, 'groups' is always returned, just not sorted.

Comment: In general, asynchronous services should return a promise so that the controller can use the promise's `.then` method. If the code doesn't return a promise, how can the client code know when the data is fulfilled by the server? Or know if there was an error?

Comment: @georgeawg - uh...ok, Yeah, thats how promises work.  But your response, vague at best, does not address my issue at all.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not getting into an argument with you.  Your rating implies you probably created stackoverflow.  That being said, I am not looking for code samples to solve my issue, but I am looking for suggestions on where I should be attempting to "sort" my results.  I thought doing so in the service would work, but its not.  Then I thought I could sort the results in the controller when returned from the service....but that to is not working.

Comment: Design the service so that it returns a promise. Do subsequent processing such as sorting by chaining. For more information see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises). The chaining of subsequent processing can be done either in the service or in the controller.